# How to install firebase using npm package manager?

Tags: firebase, npm

I know there are a lot of questions on stackoverflow and other sites about this, but despite all the answers given I couldn't solve my problem. For a while I have been trying to install firebase in my MERN Stack project from the command  `npm i firebase --save` . Despite this I still get the following errors:

```
npm i firebase --save
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/firebase failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-url
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-15T22_23_35_935Z-debug.log
```

After multiple searches on the Internet, I executed the following command  then,  `npm clear cache --force` `npm clean cache --force` but without success. I even tried this command  `npm i firebase --force` unfortunately I get the same errors. I even copy-pasted the node_modules firebase package from another project where I had managed to install it and copied the following line into my package.json file `"firebase": "^9.8.2",` so that npm recognizes this package, unfortunately npm didn't recognize it because when I run I always get the same missing module errors related to firebase. I do not really know what else to do.

Comment: That error looks like it would cause any package install to fail, not just firebase: *getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-url*

Comment: So how to import the firebase package from another react project into this one and be able to use it.

Comment: This problem only affects me in firebase and creating a reactjs project from the command line. Installing my other packages works great

Comment: I found the solution on this [url](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this [url](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc) which is

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

this will cause npm to use `http` instead of `https`. This means that npm will no longer be secure and will download without performing a prior check to know if I am on the right site. It is possible that it is my ISP that is blocking my connection to this site because I do not use a proxy.